# How to remove tumblr controls / buttons / iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, tumblr

I've tried the following codes to remove the controls / buttons / iframe from my Tumblr. None of them seem to work with the new control bar.

```
#tumblr_controls { display: none;}

<script>
var T_C = document.getElementById('tumblr_controls');
T_C.parentNode.removeChild(T_C);
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just checked, Tumblr does not seem to be using the id `tumblr_controls` anymore, that is most probably the reason your code is not working. Try this;

```
body > iframe:first-child { display: none !important; }
```

This selector selects any `iframe` that is the first child directly under `body`.

If you have some script putting something else in the beginning remove the `:first-child` (make sure you do not have any other `iframe` directly under `body`). Optionally you can use the new class(es) Tumblr is using to select the element you want to hide, but that way when Tumblr changes the class(es) your code will stop working.

An example of how the element in question looks like now:

```
<iframe class="tmblr-iframe tmblr-iframe--desktop-loggedin-controls iframe-controls--desktop" name="desktop-loggedin-controls" scrolling="no" src="https://www.tumblr.com/dashboard/iframe?tumblelogName=example" width="0" frameborder="0" height="0">

... codes ...

</iframe>
```

Comment: OH YOU BEAUTIFUL GENIOUS! Thank you so much! This totally worked!!

Comment: Hey also make sure you check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34115099/)(question here on SO that was asked after you),  Tumblr seems to do things a little differently on mobile devices.

Answer (score 2):

In my tumblr there were two iframes following the body tag... so I made it like this. Hope it helps!

```
body > iframe:first-child, body > iframe:nth-child(2) {display: none;}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the enlightenment!

Following your answer, I had to inspect the page, find the first appearance of an `iframe` below the body of the page, take the full class, then, `display: none`.

Here is the CSS code that worked for me using the default Tumblr theme:

`.tmblr-iframe-compact .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls {display: none;}`

It's important to mention that just unchecking "Promote Tumblr" wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on a "custom html" Tumblr page, it just displays my HTML, CSS and JS no posts or tumblr feed. The Tumblr "open app" and "follow" `iframe` dialogs were obscuring the menu navigation on mobile.

I inserted the `<style>` block inside `<head>` at end and directly underneath the beginning `<body>` tags.

```
    <style>
        body>iframe:first-child {
            display: none !important;
        }
    
        .iframe-controls-container .iframe-controls-container.iframe-controls-container--unified .tmblr-iframe,
        .tmblr-iframe--unified-controls,
        .tmblr-iframe--loaded .iframe-controls--desktop .iframe-controls--phone-mobile {
            display: none !important;
        }
    </style>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just wanted to say that yes, it STILL works! I've made a small music player for a notion setup (used Tumblr as a free host) AND I WAS DYINGGGGGG for a solution because body > iframe:first-child { display: none !important; } DID NOT TAKE OFF THE EMBED'S IFRAME!!!! Now my tumblr embed is completely free of it's branding!!!!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).