# Tumblr white bar appears on top of my mobile theme after disabling Follow button through code

Tags: html, iframe, themes, tumblr

So, as of `4/12/15`, Tumblr has changed something in their code and the `"Promote Tumblr!"` buttons reappeared on my blog, even if I had them disabled in the advanced settings...

I searched and found this code:

```
iframe:first-child { display: none !important; }
```

that worked for me, but now on the mobile version of the site, I get a plain white bar on top, right where the Tumblr Promote buttons used to be... On desktop, everything works ok...

I attached the screenshots of before and after here:

Before:
[image: Before],

After:
[image: After]

Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think that may be a second iframe showing up. Try this: "body > iframe:first-child, body > iframe:nth-child(2) {display: none;}"

Answer (score 1):

That is because Tumblr seem to add this class "tmblr-iframe--controls-phone-container" to the body and this style;

```
.tmblr-iframe--controls-phone-container {
    padding-top: 43px;
}
```

from what I found.
Try: `body { padding-top: 0 !important; }`

You can use the "Developer Tools" in Chrome (desktop browser) to see the source `HTML` of your site on different mobile devices, that should help you with problems like this.

Note: I used the "Developer Tools" in Chrome Browser and was emulating a device called "iPhone 5" to recreate the issue in question.